# jQuery Multiselect - Select All and with Filtered Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

When you use the `search feature`, and then use the `select_all` it does not work together, it selects "everything" as if the search made no change, but the search itself "hides" the elements. It should only select all to the items that are `visible`

Wondering if someone else has had this issue or knows a solution to it. Thanks again if anyone can be of assistance!

Using the **jQuery MultiSelect Plugin**:
http://loudev.com

This is the code I'm currently using, the search utilizes the `quicksearch` js

```
$('.multiSelect').multiSelect({
  selectableHeader: "<div><a href='#' id='select-all'>select all</a></div><input type='text' class='search-input form-control' autocomplete='off' placeholder='search' style='margin-bottom:5px'>",
  selectionHeader: "<div><a href='#' id='deselect-all'>deselect all</a></div><input type='text' class='search-input form-control' autocomplete='off' placeholder='search' style='margin-bottom:5px'>",
  afterInit: function(ms){
    var that = this,
        $selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev(),
        $selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev(),
        selectableSearchString = '#'+that.$container.attr('id')+' .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
        selectionSearchString = '#'+that.$container.attr('id')+' .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';

    that.qs1 = $selectableSearch.quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
    .on('keydown', function(e){
      if (e.which === 40){
        that.$selectableUl.focus();
        return false;
      }
    });

    that.qs2 = $selectionSearch.quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
    .on('keydown', function(e){
      if (e.which == 40){
        that.$selectionUl.focus();
        return false;
      }
    });
  },
  afterSelect: function(){
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  },
  afterDeselect: function(){
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
  }
});


$('#select-all').on('click',function(){
  $('.multiSelect').multiSelect('select_all');
  return false;
});

$('#deselect-all').on('click',function(){
  $('.multiSelect').multiSelect('deselect_all');
  return false;
});
```

jsfiddle for demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/b8ygzqca/6/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue yesterday.  I too looked around for solution, but only found your post.  So here is my solution.  Please note that I actually updated the source code to get my solution to work.  I modified the 'select_all' function:

```
'select_all': function () {
        var that = this,
            ms = this.$element,
            values = ms.val(),
            selectables = this.$selectableUl.find('.ms-elem-selectable').filter(':not(.' + this.options.disabledClass + ')').filter(':visible');

        ms.find('option:not(":disabled")')
            .filter(function (index) {
                var it = this,
                    msValue = selectables
                        .filter(function () {
                            return $(this).data('ms-value') === it.value;
                        })
                        .data('ms-value');
                return msValue === this.value;
            })
            .prop('selected', true);
        selectables.addClass('ms-selected').hide();
        this.$selectionUl.find('.ms-optgroup-label').show();
        this.$selectableUl.find('.ms-optgroup-label').hide();
        this.$selectionUl
            .find('.ms-elem-selection')
            .filter(':not(.' + this.options.disabledClass + ')')
            .filter(function (index) {
                return that.$selectableUl.find('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('-selection', '-selectable') + '.ms-selected' ).length === 1;
            })
            .addClass('ms-selected')
            .show();
        this.$selectionUl.focus();
        ms.trigger('change');
        if (typeof this.options.afterSelect === 'function') {
            var selectedValues = $.grep(ms.val(), function (item) {
                return $.inArray(item, values) < 0;
            });
            this.options.afterSelect.call(this, selectedValues);
        }
    },
```

I added a 'that' var and then added extra filter calls on this.$selectableUl and this.$selectionUl. I also updated how the options on ms are selected. Hopefully this will work for you too.

Comment: I should note that I am only using the quicksearch on the selectable list.  I imagine I'd need to do something similar to the deselect_all function too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and based on my tests, you don't need to change the source code.

Simply in your `afterInit` do `prev()` & `find()`, as below:

```
selectableHeader: "<div class='myDiv'><input type='text autocomplete='off'></div>"

$selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev().find('input'),
$selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev().find('input'),
```

Keep in mind for each `div` you have before the `input`, you need to do `prev()`. For instance:

```
selectableHeader: "<div class='mydDiv'><input type='text'autocomplete='off'><a href='#' id='select-all'>Add All</a></div><div class='myExtraDiv'></div>
```

You would need to do:

```
$selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev().prev().find('input')
```

Since the first `prev()`, would get `<div class='myExtraDiv'></div>` and your 2nd `prev()` would *fetch* the correct `input`.

*Tips:* Run `console.log($selectableSearch);` to see what you've selected with `prev()`

Hope this help someone!